# How can I change the order of list elements using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ul li as below:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

How can I change the order of list elements using Jquery? So that on load, the new list should look like:

```
<ul id="list">
        <li>2</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to achieve using Jquery?

Comment: Do you want to randomize it?

Comment: This question is too broad and doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: any specific pattern in changing order like sorting etc, or just swap first and second li elements.

Comment: the solution will depend on what sorting logic you want to use... your problem does not give any pointers for us

Comment: No complex logics, just simply interchange first and last one. No sorting or pattern in changing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

USe like this,

```
$("#list li:eq(0)").before($("#list li:eq(1)"));
```

`eq`  selector selects the element with index. Then you can use `before()` or `after()` to change the postion .

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/233/)

Answer (score 6):

your jquery would be .
you can use insertBefore.

```
$('#list').find('li:eq(1)').insertBefore('li:eq(0)');
```

**[DEMO](http://liveweave.com/vrpr5H)**

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
var lists = $('#list li');
lists.filter(':contains(2)').insertBefore(lists.filter(':contains(1)'));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5dw4d/)

or

```
var lists = $('#list li');
lists.filter(':nth-child(2)').insertBefore(lists.filter(':nth-child(1)'));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5dw4d/1/)

Answer (score 3):

To make the first one last regardless of number of items:

```
$("#list li:last").after($("#list li:first"));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j3F53/)

Answer (score 2):

```
   $("#list").prepend($("li:eq(1)"));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/235/)**

or

```
 $("li:eq(1)").prependTo("#list");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/234/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you use html like this:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

you can use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)/[`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) or [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)/[`prependTo`](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/) to manipulate lists and other `DOM` nodes:

```
var $list = $('#list'),
    $items = $list.children(),
    $firstItem = $items.first();

//remove first item from DOM
$firstItem.detach();
//set first item after second
$items.eq(1).after($firstItem);
```

And after this you will have such list:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>2</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/wAkwV/)

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ezvnp/117/)   try this,

```
  alert($('li').eq(0).insertAfter($('li').eq(1)));
```